# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^2+1)^{n/(n^2+1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I can't figure out how to solve this limit:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^2+1)^{n/(n^2+1)}$$

I can calculate the limit of the power which is $0$, but then appears the indetermination ($\infty^0$).

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: $(n^2+1)^{n/(n^2+1)}=[(1+1/n^2)^{n^2}]^{n/(n^2(n^2+1))}[n^{1/n}]^{2n^2/(n^2+1)}$. In the first factor, the base tends to $e$ and the exponent to $0$. In the second factor, the base tends to $1$ and the exponent to $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know $n^{1/n}\to 1,$ you can say

$$1\le (n^2+1)^{n/(n^2+1)} \le (2n^2)^{1/n}=2^{1/n}(n^{1/n})^2 \to 1\cdot 1^2 =1.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me so much... it's more practical too :)

Answer (score 2):

By continuity of $x\mapsto e^x$ and $x\mapsto\log x$ we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (n^2+1)^{\frac n{n^2+1}} = e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\log(n^2+1)}{n^2+1}} = e^0 = 1.
$$

Comment: Thanks, i will try to use your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If your limit exists and equals $L$, then
$$
\ln L
 = \ln \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} (n^2+1)^\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)
 = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \ln \left( (n^2+1)^\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)
$$
Can you finish?

**UPDATE**

$$
\begin{split}
\ln L
 &= \ln \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} (n^2+1)^\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right) \\
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \ln \left( (n^2+1)^\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right) \\
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{n}{n^2+1} \ln \left(n^2+1\right) \\
\end{split}
$$
Note that asymptotically $n^2 +1 \approx n^2$ so you have
$$
\frac{n \ln \left(n^2+1\right)}{n^2+1}
= n \times \frac{\ln \left(n^2+1\right)}{\ln\left(n^2\right)}
  \times \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \times \frac{\ln\left(n^2\right)}{n^2}
\approx \frac{n \ln \left(n^2\right)}{n^2}
= \frac{2n \ln n}{n^2}
= 0,
$$
(which can be formalized by noting that the middle two fractions both converge to $1$ as $n \to \infty$).

Can you find $L$ now?

Comment: I will verify, thanks

Comment: I think not.  There will be $\lim \limits{n\to∞}ln(n^2 +1)$ but that ln is also ∞ which to me gives again an indeterminate form.

Comment: @CookieDog please see the update

Comment: I'm in the stage at if i'm using methods other than remarkable and fundamental limits, I'll get into some trouble with my teacher, that's why I can't use aproximations or the L'Hospital's rule

Comment: @CookieDog made one more step